# Closed communicating class

Tags: stochastic-processes, proof-writing, markov-chains

[image]

Let $P_{ij}$ a transition matrix, a class $C$ is closed if given two different states $i$ and $j$ $$i\in C, i\rightarrow j\Rightarrow j\in C$$

If a Markov Chain is irreducible the transition matrix have no closed communicating class, right?

What I do not understand this exercise, it seems to me that the first part contradicts the second. Because if I found a transition matrix with no closed communicating class how I can show that every transition matrix has at least one closed communicating class.

Comment: "if I found a transition matrix with no closed communicating class" Did you? Then show it (otherwise what are we talking about?).

Comment: @Did I thought that in both cases the space was finite,

Comment: Offtopic. The question is whether you found a transition matrix with no closed communicating class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closed communicating class might be the whole set.
For the second part, you will need an infinite state-space.